# How to hide image path from source code using PHP

Tags: php

I want to hide image path from website. To do that first I did this:

```
<?php
// get image path
$path = 'images/profiles/uploads/' . $list['thumbnail'];
$type = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$data = file_get_contents($path);
$base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);
?>
```

But this is very slow, So I try to implement like this, but code is not working:

`download.php`:

```
function setImgDownload($imagePath) {           
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($imagePath);
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    imagejpeg($image);
}
```

`mypage.php`:

```
<?php include('download.php'); ?>
<img src="<?php setImgDownload('images/Chrysanthemum.jpg') ?>" width="300"/>
```

If I put function and call function at the same page it's working:

```
function setImgDownload($imagePath) {
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($imagePath);
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    imagejpeg($image);
}

setImgDownload('images/Chrysanthemum.jpg');
```

How to keep function in separate page?

Comment: if someone wants to steal your images they can't be stopped

Comment: @Dagon If he want to steel image It is ok, I just want to hide server path

Comment: did you tried `return` from function

Comment: @zan I have tried but not working

Comment: Which restriction you want to add? You can create script for image view

Comment: whats the point exactly?

Comment: @Dagon as I said I want to hide I mage page for example, images/profiles/abc.jpg I want to display like abc.jpg. without path

Comment: yes, but why??? whats the end game?

Comment: @Dagon think about two tire arc, I get data from one layer when I display data I want to hide admin layer path

Comment: you don't hide the path, and hiding it adds no security - so um. oh well some people

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try changing your mypage.php to

```
<?php
   include('download.php');
   echo "<img src='".setImgDownload('images/Chrysanthemum.jpg')."' width='300'/>"; // calling function inside php
?>
```

Here, instead creating the HTML element outside php, put it inside php using echo and just escape while calling the php function. This should give you what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it worked in my case within the local php file:

```
$image = 'images/Chrysanthemum.jpg';

$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($image);
ob_start();
  imagejpeg( $image, NULL, 100 );
  imagedestroy( $image );
  $i = ob_get_clean();

echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode( $i ).'" width="200">';
```